# How do I remove a Lightning cable that is stuck in a USB port?

Tags: usb, lightning

I inserted the USB end of the lightning to USB cable that came with the iPhone 5 into a D-Link USB hub. When I tried to unplug the cable, it seemed impossible to remove. I tried using a screw driver to pry the connector out, but it didn't move with a reasonable amount of pressure. I tried using a piece of rubber to improve my grip on the connector, but that didn't work.

How do I safely extract the cable from the hub?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a [discussion on this topic on the Apple forums](https://discussions.apple.com/message/20132975#20132975). I tested a few of the solutions, including using a plastic collar stay, but the suggestion that worked was using two thin cardboard strips to release the grip. What worked for me:

1. Find a thin, semi-glossy business card, or similar piece of cardboard and cut it into two strips about the width of the USB port. You can use an un-occupied port to make sure the strip is narrow enough to fit.
2. Insert the strips on the two wide sides of the USB port, between the outside of the cable's plug and the inside of the USB port. You may need to work the strips back and forth to get them in. I had to insert the strips to about 2/3 the depth of the port. If you have difficulty inserting the cardboard, you may need a thinner material.
3. Grasp the sandwich of the cardboard strips and the USB plug. Pull. The plug should come out as easily as a normal plug would.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem.  Once the USB plug was out, I used a utility knife blade to carefully scrape a 45 degree angle bevel from each of the four holes in the plug on the side that is farthest from the wire.  I still have to wiggle the plug to get it out, but it is much easier.  If you try this, remember you will be creating tiny metal flakes, so blow the plug out before plugging it into anything.  Be very careful not to damage the wires inside the plug holes.

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me so far.

WARNING!!!! dont try this method if there is still power on the usb port. you are basicly shoving a piece of metal inside of it ! Please be carefull for yourself and your products. i am not responsible for any damage you do in this proces.

1. get a soda can and empty it out
2. get a knife or scissor, and cut the top and bottom off.
3. Cut the middle piece in half, so all thats left is a sheet of tin. Cut a rectangle shape out of it the size of the usb port, and fold it 1 or 2 times.
4. Insert the piece you have made into the side where there is no logo printed 1/3 2/3 in (I think this is only on the official usb cable, the original cable has holes drilled into them at the back side, you are pushing the latches out of those holes ).
5. pull the piece of tin back with the usb cable at the same time, and it should be fixed. it pulles really easily. i hope this fixed your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I used an eyelash curler. It had a better grip on the part barely sticking out